# Google MAP not loading with custom markers

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've read other questions regarding Google MAP API, and none of them seem to address my issue, as far as I can tell.  I followed the "outdated" instructions for installing Google Maps on my site with a MySQL query and custom markers.  After correcting all the errors being generated by the sample code, I finally have the xml file being generated properly, (http://www.l3valuation.com/portal/maptest2.php).

However, when loading the actual map page, all I am getting is a white page with no map.  No errors are being generated either.  If this has been answered before and I missed it, I do apologize.  My eyes are becoming hazy and I could have missed it.

My code for the map page is as follows

```
   <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>L3 CARDS</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
   #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var customLabel = {
      1: {
label: 'A'
  },
  2: {
label: 'I'
  },
        3: {
label: 'L'
  },
  4: {
    label: 'R'
 }
  5: {
    label: 'G'
  }
};

function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.3791021, -122.7613788),
      zoom: 15
    });
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('maptest2.php', function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
var ReportType = markerElem.getAttribute('ReportType');
var Address = markerElem.getAttribute('Address');
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('Lat')),
    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
var strong = document.createElement('strong');
strong.textContent = Address
infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

var text = document.createElement('text');
text.textContent = Address
infowincontent.appendChild(text);
var icon = customLabel[ReportType] || {};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: point,
  label: icon.label
});
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }



  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ValidAPIKey is installed&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see your map div in html ..

Comment: It's in the code, but seemed to have disappeared when copying the code here.  It appears just before the <script> tag that called the custom markers.  I'll edit this to see if I can get it to display properly in this forum.

Comment: I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: It wasn't.  I was missing a comma in the custom labels.  Question has been marked as answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was missing a comma in the custom labels.